# How to identify Apple Music tracks?

Tags: itunes, ipod, apple-music

My playlist won't sync to my iPod because there's Apple Music mixed in the playlist. I didn't think I had any Apple Music in my library. How can I tell which song is Apple Music and which song I own?

Answer (score 5):

There’s no way on iOS other than turning off the Apple Music and seeing what tracks remain. (doing that, *You should retain all settings and be able to re-enable it as soon as you have your answer.*)

You can easily see this on iOS and in iTunes, though with one smart playlist. That playlist syncs to iOS so you could go that route, too:

[image]

Match **iCloud Status** is **Apple Music** and you're done on the Mac. Then you will see your Apple Music Playlist on iOS under your Library - below the Apple Music curated playlists, under the genius playlists where the Smart Playlists are indicated with a multi colored gear.

[image]

Comment: Clever use of Playlists, well done!

Answer (score 0):

this article is useful explaining the difference and how you can check this using iTunes: https://www.imore.com/how-check-if-your-macs-songs-are-uploaded-matched-purchased-or-apple-music-drm-laden

If checking Apple Music status is the sole purpose, you could use iMazing’s free trial to browse your library. With iTunes you would have to check each file manually, whereas iMazing lists the status of each track. Disclaimer: I work for the team.

1. Install iMazing on your PC or Mac (you’ll find it easily), and launch it
2. Connect an iPhone or iPad to your computer, iMazing will detect it
3. In iMazing, select the device you just connected and click the Music icon
4. Click ‘Import from iTunes’, this will show you your iTunes music library
5. Tracks marked with an Apple icon are Apple Music tracks

Comment: There is no need for a 3rd party tool, you can list all tracks from Apple Music directly in iTunes

Comment: How so? iTunes displays the cloud status of tracks, but that's not equivalent to Apple Music status. As described in the iMore article linked, the info isn't easy to get, and makes it especially cumbersome to identify Apple Music tracks in a large library.

Comment: @Gregzo If the iCloud status is "Apple Music" it's an Apple Music track. That's actually also what the article says.

Comment: Sure, but then you have to 'Get Info' on each track one by one. @bmike's answer seems like the most elegant.